# What is it called when there is an inferred context, but no direct mention of it?

Tags: single-word-requests, phrase-requests, idiom-requests

Is there a name for when a comment or statement has an inferred context, but there is no mention of that context in the comment or statement itself?

For instance, if someone said:

> "Remember when people warned against a female president because she
>   might be irrational, vindictive, and prone to mood swings?"

The inferred context is that this is against Trump, and it is implied that he is irrational, vindictive, and prone to mood swings. However none of these connections are made in the question itself.

Many people will used this type of statement in arguments and/or debates, and then fall back on "Well I didn't actually ***say*** that, you just ***heard*** it that way." when what they ***actually*** meant was perfectly clear.

Is there a name for this type of inferred connection or context?

**P.S.** any political statements used in this question are for reference purposes only, and do not express my views, and do no warrant discussion.

Comment: I would call it a _setup_, you set a scene and let the listener complete what you set up. You cannot set up an inference, only imply the true meaning by giving a hint. Also, this setup is called _irony_ in that you know what you imply but act as if you do not know it.

Comment: Trump is female? Who knew?

Comment: ironically, i suspect you have misunderstood the point. if the context is trump, then the point is not that trump is a bad guy, but that the supposed "female" flaws of irrationality etc. are ok, since he has them all. so it's actually a point in favor of the Donald, rhetorically - it argues that guys like him do that, so it's ok for women to be moody, etc. - they're just like guys!

Comment: @mobileink The OP's opinion is one interpretation, as is yours. I agree that it could be interpreted both ways.

Comment: Don't you mean an implied context not an inferred one?

Comment: @tchrist you are correct.  Actually what I was really looking for here was if there was a word to describe this type of implied context, in the context of an argument or debate. I'll have to word my question better next time!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I would call that type of inferred connect or context an **implication**:

> #### Implication
>
> - The conclusion that can be drawn from something although it is not explicitly stated
>
> *He said they acted voluntarily, adding that there was no implication of fraud.*

([OD](https://en.oxforddictionaries.com/definition/implication))

Comment: So we could say that the accusation in this case was _implied_?

Comment: Yes, you could also say that the speaker was *implying* that Trump is *irrational, vindictive, and prone to mood swings* without actually saying he is.